# Java Server Socket connection over different routers

Tags: java, sockets, server, connection, client

I am currently developing a client and a server for a small game.
The client which connects to the server establishes the connection with this method:

```
// This method is called, passing on an ipv6 address and port number 6666
        public void startConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                //some other code handling responses
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.debug("Error when initializing connection", e);
                throw new IOException();
            }

        }
```

The Server I built accepts connections using this method:

```
 public void start(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port); //port = 6666
//This part is used to handle multiple connections at once
        while (b){
            try {
                map.add(new EchoClientHandler(serverSocket.accept())); //EchoClientHandler is a class used to send and receive data instructions 
                x = map.size() - 1;
                System.out.println("Establishing connection from port " + port);
                map.get(x).start();
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                
            }
        }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Both methods work fine and establish a stable connection between the client and the server, but when i try and establish a connection from different routers or general internet connections (like via cellular data) it doesn't work.
Is there a way to establish connections without both the client and the server having to connect from the same router?

Edit:
Here is the error i get from the client, the server doesn't show anything:

```
18:03:24.288 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG dorusblanken.werwolfclient.Client - Error when initializing connection

java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

Comment: Can you give more details about "it doesn't work"? If you're getting an error, please copy and paste it to the question

Comment: That is about the only error I get @Joni

Comment: Several pieces of bad practice here. 1. The server does not 'establish' connections, it *accepts* them. 2. You haven't set a timeout, so the `SocketTimeoutException` you're catching cannot possibly be thrown. 3. Your `map` variable is obviously not a `Map` at all, it is a `List` of some kind. 4. Your method of putting an object into the list and then getting it back rather than saving it in a variable in the first place is poor. 5. Catch-and-log-and-throw is poor practice. Just let the exception be thrown, and logged by the caller. If you can log it here you can log it there.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne 1. Rather new to this so forgive me for the wrong terms 2. The code is abbreviated and I removed the timeout part I'll edit the try catch block out later. 3. You got a point there, I recently changed it from a map to a list but was too lazy to change the name 4. That's because I handle multiple clients at once and I first store the client and then start it because it seemed more convenient (if you have a better solution I'm open) 5. Also got a point there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Network is unreachable" means there is no way to get to the destination network from the current network.

You mentioned that you are trying to establish a connection via the Internet. For that to work, the destination host (your server) must be connected to the Internet, it must have a public IP address, and the clients need to use the public IP address when connecting.

That is the simplest configuration. Most companies don't actually put their servers directly on the Internet. Instead, the public IP frequently belongs to a CDN or DDoS mitigation layer, which forwards connections to a load balancer, and the load balancer forwards connections to servers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After a painfully long time I set up port forwarding on my router and it works perfectly now.